# Why does checkbox gets checked on a click event for submit

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using a jquery form to submit the interests for users. What I am using is something like a checkbox value, they are seperate and I use className to get their values.

The issue that I have to face is whether I select both of them or none of them or just a single of them. I get them both checked when I click the button that will submit the form using Ajax, so that results in an opposite result.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
var getInterest = "";
if ($(".interestedInMale").attr('checked', 'checked') && 
  $(".interestedInFemale").attr('checked', 'checked')) {
   getInterest = "Females, Males";
} else if ($(".interestedInMale").attr('checked', 'checked')) {
   getInterest = "Males";
} else if ($(".interestedInFemale").attr('checked', 'checked')) {
   getInterest = "Females";
} else {
   getInterest = "";  
}
```

What should happen is that it should just provide me with the values, not alter the values but what it does is opposite, it first changes the value I mean checks them both, and then submits the form having the total value `Females, Males`. And this is not what I want.

Below this code is the ajax submit block. And above this is the function declaration as:

```
function submitThis() {
```

Any help for what I am doing wrong? Also, you can give me a better suggestion for getting the values of Checkbox fields in jQuery Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the setter version of .attr() here, `.attr('checked', 'checked')` sets the `checked` attribute value to `checked`.

The correct solution to use problem is to check the value of the checked property, it can be done using [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is) and [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector as given below

```
var getInterest = "",
    $chkmale = $(".interestedInMale"),
    $chkfmale = $(".interestedInFemale");
if ($chkmale.is(':checked') && $chkfmale.is(':checked')) {
    getInterest = "Females, Males";
} else if ($chkmale.is(':checked')) {
    getInterest = "Males";
} else if ($chkfmale.is(':checked')) {
    getInterest = "Females";
} else {
    getInterest = "";
}
```

Comment: why not get a bool version of `.is(':checked')`  and remove the last else part.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
$(".interestedInMale").attr('checked', 'checked')
```

checks the checkbox with the class selector `.interestedInMale`.
Use the code below to test if it is checked

```
if ($(".interestedInMale").is(':checked')) { }
```